# How to prevent changes from inspect element?

Tags: apex

I had tried with key press prevention and also tried option of reassigning values using java script but in this case changes from UI also loss.
so if there is any other option to prevent inspect element to impact values then please help me out.

Comment: I don't think you can completely control this thing. but can try few thing like disable right click,  disable f12  keys.

Comment: But in this case we can still make changes with inspect element

Comment: thats what I am saying in first line. but we you do these thing then normal user won't be able to open inspect element and make changes.

Comment: The client-side of an app can always be tampered with (as exactly what tool or browser is used is outside your control). So security measures have to be imposed by the server-side. What problem are you trying to address here?

Comment: @TusharSharma Please never mess with the operating system's or browser's functionality, it only degrades UX.  If your page design requires that the user doesn't right click, redesign your page.

Comment: This question has *nothing* to do with Salesforce. It also represents a deep misunderstanding of how internet technology works at a basic level.

Answer (score 1):

A properly implemented browser won't allow you to change its core functionality via Javascript.  At least in Firefox, you can even prevent pages from disabling right-clicking or key presses.  There may be some clever way to fool browsers (e.g., `onclick = "return false;"`), but this doesn't really matter to you, because anyone who can access your page can send you whatever data they want, even if they end up having to manually write POST requests themselves to do it.

You should never trust that your users are sending you the data you expect.  Do all your data validation on the server side through your controller, triggers, validation rules, etc, and if desired you can replicate those rules in Javascript to give your users validation without having to submit their form.  Depending on your use case, it may be acceptable to use `ActionFunction` or Javascript Remoting to allow you to write validation in Apex and call it remotely from the page, then also double check it when the data is submitted.  AJAX does incur a time and resource cost beyond just regular Javascript, but this method is somewhat easier to maintain since it avoids having to repeat code in two languages.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is. you can just show the details on html but when you call controller then you can verify the values there too. as i did my side,that is i am showing the calculation on client side on label, but at time of saving it i calculate again in backend and store that value rather then taking from any label or textbox.